# Is role="tooltip" important?

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers, uiaccessibility

1. Most Screen readers read the custom tooltip information by default. role="tooltip" does not seem to do anything additional, like it doesnt inform user that its tooltip. Why do we need to use role="tooltip" for the tooltip container? Any specific purpose?
2. Tooltip information not read by NVDA in IE11. Any hacks to fix?

Here's my code:

```
<div class="ttipcontainer">
  <button title="" class="co_tooltipElement" id="newButton05-2" aria-describedby="coid_accessibleTooltip_1"> Recent Searches </button> 
  <span tabindex="-1" class="co_accessibilityLabel" id="coid_accessibleTooltip_1" aria-hidden="true" role="tooltip">Shows information of your recent searches</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heydon Pickering has a great guide on writing [Accessible Toggle Tips](https://inclusive-components.design/tooltips-toggletips/#tooltipasprimarylabel). In it he describes why we put the `role=tooltip` on an element:

> Note the use of the tooltip role. In practical terms, all this role offers is an assurance that aria-describedby works reliably where supported. As Léonie Watson writes, [ARIA labels and descriptions sometimes don't work with all elements](https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2017/07/short-note-on-aria-label-aria-labelledby-and-aria-describedby/) unless you incorporate an appropriate role. In this case, the most important role is the implicit button role of the subject  element, but role="tooltip" may extend support for this labeling method in some software.

So although it doesn't provide much additional information, it does help the `aria-describedby` point to an element with a valid role, which helps ensure it will work properly for some screen readers.